# What kind of bike do I have, "manufacturer/model"

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

I just bought this bike at a garage sale, mainly because i was told by my friend of how amazing of a deal it was, that this particular bike was worth at least 3 times the amount I paid.

Anyways I clearly do not know much about bikes and I am unable to actually read or make out the decals.

I do have the serial number found under the crank. I'm hoping that someone will be able to tell me where I could find out this info, or by looking at the pics and the serial number what I actually have.

SN: CYIDC11C02155

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Heat tube badge is "motobecane" which used to be a well-reputed French brand which went bust in the 1980s.    But it says USA which means its from the US company that aquired the trademarks and this is simply a rebadged asian bike frame.  The frame size is labelled as 49cm which is quite small, suiting a shorter-legged adult.

However your example has been seriously modified - for a start its a fixed speed/single speed flipflop hub so someone has removed all the gear system.

Also noted that it has only one brake, and the person building it didn't leave any hood replacements on the bars. Meaning that the Hoods hand position is going to be unusable, possibly why the bars are cocked up at an angle.

Workaround - dummy hoods.  Go read this question for more  [How do I use retro drop down handlebars with no hoods?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/12974/how-do-i-use-retro-drop-down-handlebars-with-no-hoods)

Consider that 90+% of the braking effect comes from the front brake, riding one back brake is limiting your ability to stop.  And if you're in a singlespeed then you only have one brake, which is not redundant and therefore not legal in many parts of the world.

Also noted it has a suspension seatpost, which sound great but in reality simply interfere with your leg height while riding.

Another option is to try contacting MotobecaneUSA with the serial number and see what they say.  Don't expect a lot.

Comment: oniner or "0niner" doesn't come up in any catalogues, so might be some random sticker the builder fitted.

Comment: Thank you for  that info on my bike,  this may be a question that your unable to give an accurate answer to due to the info/pics I provided but with the info I have provided could you give me an idea of what this bike may be worth?  Or simply how much would you pay for it, top and bottom dollar?? I ask because my buddy convinced me that this bike was worth way more than I paid for it and I want to know if he needs to have his ass beat ha ha lol

Comment: It’s not great pic, but I think it’s got rear-facing dropouts, so it might have been sold as a fixie/single rather than stripped of gears. A drive side photo would be helpful as would a photo of the decal on the downtube.

Comment: @JoshuaJRoose read our [tour]  Sales valuations are off topic.   Its worth around 3c US per kilo as scrap steel, a bit more for aluminium.   Any bike is better than walking, and its hard to ride without some kind of bike.  Feel free to join the [chat] for a less structured discussion.

Comment: "90+% of the braking effect comes from the front brake" That's overstating it, isn't it? It's more like 75% or something. But, still, if you only have one brake, make it the front one. And then add a back brake anyway.

Comment: @JoshuaJRoose You should have told your friend 'if it's worth so much more than the asking price, you buy it!'

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a Motobecane  (a brand sold by on line discount retailer BikesDirect) single speed frame. The decal/stickers are from a Niner brand bike. The "O" is actually a stylized "9". If it were in fact an actual Niner built bike you may have gotten a deal. Niner does build some high end units. The headbadge is the likely deal killer. It is more likely the stickers  were added than the headbadge.

Comment: The current BikesDirect fixies appear to have welded-on cable stops on the top tube.  The are absent in OP's photos.

Comment: 'The "O" is actually a stylized "9" ' Font fail! Though I admit it's _slightly_ clearer in when you can see the whole glyph in the [company's logo](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0061/0022/2050/t/6/assets/niner-logo-vector.svg?48330). But it still looks more like a weirdly drawn script zero than a nine.